# How to filter a specific column to get the largest and smallest value?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, html-table

I have a table that consists of a few columns and I am not using table from datatable. I want to filter my 7th column which is consist of numbers to give the highest and lowest value.
[image]

This is the column that I want to filter.

I do not have any idea to do this filtering or it is using any Math.max and Math.min?

```
<table id="example" border="2" class="display" style="width: 100%">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class="header">
                                                <th> Activity</th>
                                                <th> Comment </th>
                                                <th> Rating Question 1</th>
                                                <th> Rating Question 2</th>
                                                <th> Rating Question 3</th>
                                                <th> Total Rating</th>
                                                <th> Date </th>
                                                <th> Time </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>


   rootRef2.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
        rootRef2 = childSnapshot.val();
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.activity));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.comment));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.ratingSmiley1));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.ratingStar));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.ratingSmiley2));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.totalRating));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.date));
        tr.appendChild(createCell(rootRef2.time));
        table.appendChild(tr);
    });
```

this is how i create the table

Comment: please share code

Comment: How is your data represented?

Comment: @ShayaUlman I already update the code

Comment: @brk i already update the code